# Are there adaptations of Moby Dick that try to emulate the novel's diverse use of genre/styles?

Tags: moby-dick, herman-melville, adaptation-comparison, adaptations

The novel *Moby Dick* uses many different genres of writing (most famously the encyclopedia-style chapter on whale types, but also play-scripts, Shakespeare-style soliloquies, sermons, etc.).

Are there any adaptations that try to emulate this range of genres/styles? For example, a film version may shift to a nature documentary style to enumerate the different kinds of whales.

Comment: Mark Rascovich's The Bedford Incident might qualify. The movie of the same title (1965) was an excellent thriller, but I remember the book as being well-written. I guess I'll have to read it again before I could propose this as an answer.

Comment: And I was wrong. The book refers to Moby Dick both directly and indirectly several times. For example, the ship's captain, on discovering that a visiting journalist knows nothing about Moby Dick, clearly decides that he is a clod! 
I still think the book is a good read: the writing is competent, and the author knows both the sea and the navy (and I suspect loved Moby Dick) but it is not experimental.